# Why do I have to set VerticalScroll.Value twice?

Tags: vb.net, scroll

I've got a Windows form that contains a picturebox that holds images of differing size - width is always the width of the form, height is calculated to keep the aspect ratio steady.

The up & down arrows (and home, end keys) are configured to scroll the window - but I'm finding I have to make the following call twice to 'properly' scroll:

```
Me.VerticalScroll.Value += 100
Me.VerticalScroll.Value += 100
```

The first call changes the scroll position (but not the scrollbar position), then the second changes the scrollbar position.

Why is this? Am I setting the wrong option here?

Comment: It is probably because you have the AutoScroll property set to true.  Which means that Winforms automatically scrolls, you are not supposed to mess with the scrollbar yourself.  Use the AutoScrollPosition property instead.